# General formula to calculate 3d-space equal distances

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

it's probably not the right place to post this but i don't know where else to post it.

i have 5 lines (d1 -> d5) equally distributed from each other in 3d perspective, i have the values of (a) angle, (d1) and (b5). i need to calculate (b2, b3, b4, d2, d3, d4, d5) with jquery.

[image]

i can calculate d5 with:

```
d5 = d1 - ( b5 * Math.tan(a))
```

but i have no idea how to calculate b2, b3 and b4. (d1 is divided into 4 identical segaments (s))
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be http://math.stackexchange.com that you want. +1 for the picture anyway.

Comment: First - this question is awesome. Second - @popnoodles is probably correct. Third - are you looking for length values for each line segment?

Comment: @popnoodles: thanks i'll post there now

Comment: @lunchmeat317: yes i need the length of the lines b2, b3, b4, d2, d3, d4, d5

Comment: I'm looking at this, and remembering my SOHCAHTOA from trig class. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing an easy solution here - you need at least one side to extrapolate a full triangle. Unfortunately, I can't see a way to extrapolate the length of one of the sections you don't have...you've only got angles. However, the dudes on the math forums are likely WAY better than I am at this, so they may be able to find a solution that doesn't require some type of 2d projection of a 3d object.

Comment: @lunchmeat317: i've been trying for a week to solve the problem and finally gave up, i posted it in math forums hopefully someone would be able to come with a solution.

Comment: What does *jQuery* have to do with it???

Comment: @Jared Farrish: i need to calculate the lengths with jquery

Comment: @razzak - I'm not sure if you can do this easily without some type of coordinate conversion. You'd have to take your two-dimensional object (your plane), transform it in 3D space, and then project it onto a planer viewport. That would give you what you need. Unfortunately, the math for that is beyond me (right now) but I'll be damned if it doesn't have me intrigued...can you post the link to the question on math.stackoverflow.com? I'd sure like to see if there's another way to do this. Always love learning new stuff.

Comment: *Javascript*. jQuery is a library for selecting and manipulating DOM elements. Have you heard of [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)? It's possible someone may have posted an example along those lines. Or maybe processing.js.

Comment: So is the distance between d1 and d2, the same as from d2 to d3, and son on?

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon In his projection, no, due to perspective.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324240/calculating-distances-of-equally-distributed-lines-in-3d-space this's the link in the math forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a projective scale. The easiest way to do this computationally is to use homogenous coordinates, take a rectangle (like the one in the first picture below) on which V is "infinitely far to the right" and find a projective transformation that maps this rectangle to the trapezium in the second picture. The vertices of the rectangle are (0|0), (0|d1), (b5|d1), (b5|0) and the corresponding vertices of the trapezium are (0|0), (0|d1), (b5|d5), (b5|0).

[image: Illustration of a projective transformation for obtaining a projective scale]

Since these are four points of which no three are collinear, we can find a unique matrix (up to scaling) M for this transformation. After some maths, it turns out that this matrix is:

```
[d1*b5,0,0] 
[0,b5*d5,0]
[d1-d5,0,b5*d5]
```

If you want to find the coordinates b3 and d3, for instance, you can multiply this matrix with homogenous coordinates of the point in the middle of the line, i.e. the vector (0.5*b5,d1,1)^T and you get the homogenous coordinates of the point (b3|d3), which can be converted into Euclidean coordinates by dehomogenisation, i.e. dividing the first two components by the third.

In general, if you have two points (b1|d1) and (bn|dn) and want to know the coordinates of n-2 equidistant points inbetween on a projective scale like this, you can compute the coordinates bi and di as like this (in your case, n would be 5, of course):

```
let M := matrix [[d1*bn, 0, 0], [0, bn*dn, 0], [d1-dn, 0, bn*dn]]
let v := ((i-1)/(n-1)*bn, d1, 1)
let (x,y,z) := M*v
let bi := x/z and di := y/z
```

As you see, this is a simple algorithm for computing the coordinates of these projectively equidistant points, and it generalises nicely to arbitrary numbers of points.

If you'd rather have a closed formula, you can compute the bi and di directly as:

```
let bi := (bn*d1*(i-1))/(dn*n+(d1-dn)*i-d1)
let di := d1*dn*(n-1)/(dn*n+(d1-dn)*i-d1)
```

Comment: No offence, but JavaScript is a language straight from hell and I am not going to touch it. However, I don't see the problem – all you have to do is write JavaScript code for the last two lines of code that I posted, that shouldn't be to hard in any programming language. Maybe something like http://pastebin.com/T3yuyTW3.
b[1],b[5],d[1],d[5] must contain the appropriate values at the start of the programme, the other b and d entries will then be filled in the loop.
(I have no idea whether this is valid JavaScript, but that should be the gist of it)

Comment: assuming the two formulas are correct
`let bi := (bn*d1*(i-1))/(dn*n+(d1-dn)*i-d1)
let di := d1*dn*(n-1)/(dn*n+(d1-dn)*i-d1)`
if i change the angle (a) it doesn't seem to have any effect on the formula!

Comment: sorry i'm not sure i understand what bn and dn stand for, are they the coordinates of b5, d5 after the projective transformation?

Comment: In your case, bn and dn are simply b5 resp. d5. I just called it bn and dn to be more general; the method I showed you works for n points on the line, not only for 5. In the more general setting, bn and dn are simply the coordinates of the n-th point, i.e. the rightmost point. And, yes, these are the coordinates after the transformation, which you said in your post you already know. The corresponding coordinates before the transformation are, of course, bn and d1, or in your case b5 and d1. Just put in b5 for bn and d5 for dn and you'll be fine.

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't seem to be working, here's the fiddlejs link: http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/MfBWj/

Comment: The problem is not with my code. The problem is that your vanishing point, in particular with the coordinate f. for some reason that I don't understand (as I said, JavaScript is a terrible language) your f was not computed at all. In fact, you can even write something silly like "f = -42" in your "matrix" function and nothing changes. If you measure the angle, it's not even 30°, it's around 17°. If you add a `f = 228/Math.tan(30*Math.PI/180);` after the call to matrix, everything works just fine.

Comment: it works :), sorry i had a syntax error in declaring the f variable. i fixed it now and it's working like a charm, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

First we need to calculate what the length of the adjacent side of the whole triangle **d1**->**v**->**c** is (the left vertical side of it):

```
tan(Θ) = opposite / adjacent
opposite * tan(Θ) = adjacent
adjacent = opposite * tan(Θ)
adjacent = d1 * tan(a)
```

Next thing we need is to know how much off the ground each line from **v** is when it gets to line **d1**. Given that variable **s** is the same for all divisions and assuming **N** dividing segments (in this case 3), our counter is **i** that starts from 1 and goes to **N**:

```
opposite(i) = i * (d1 / N)
```

Now we need the angle that line from **v** to each marker **s** makes:

```
tan(Θi) = opposite / adjacent
Θi = arctan(opposite / adjacent)
Θi = arctan(opposite(i) / adjacent)
Θi = arctan((i * (d1 / N)) / (d1 * tan(a)))
```

Using some geometry/trig we can say that angle going from **d1** through point **c** to top of **d5** is (90° - a). We will call this angle **a'**

```
a' = 90° - a
```

Law of sines tells us that:

```
A' / sin(a') = opposite(i) / sin(b')
```

so now we solve for A' since we need some help with getting the dimensions of the orange square:

```
A' = (opposite(i) * sin (a')) / sin(b')
```

since **b'** = (**a** + **Θi**) this turns into:

```
A' = (opposite(i) * sin (90° - a)) / sin(a + Θi)
```

Same thing applied but solving for **h** in the orange triangle (see picture):

```
h / sin(90°-Θi) = A' / sin(90°)
h = (A' * sin(90°-Θi)) / sin(90°)    
b2 = h
```

Putting it all together (hopefully without copy/paste mistakes on my part) and without simplifications:

```
b2 = (((( i * (d1 / N)) * sin (90° - a)) / sin(a + Θi)) * sin(90° - arctan((i * (d1 / N)) / (d1 * tan(a))))) / sin(90°)
```

Now rinse/repeat for each value of **i** and turn into code (I would have done that but I'm too tired) :)

Comment: `tan(Θ) = opposite / adjacent --> adjacent = opposite/tan(0)` right?

Comment: yup :)  As for a', it's because triangle from points b5->d5->c has a total of 180 deg on the inside. one of those is 90 and the other is a, thus the leftover angle is 180-90-a = 90-a though you might be right about it being dependent on b5